# Is there a simple way to set 2 Variable into Range Function

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to add two variable into my vba's range function.

For exemple I would like to set a range like this but I don't know if it is possible :

```
Range("BY" & FirstVariable &":BY" & SecondVariable)
```

In order to use WorksheetFunction. Median Method :

```
Application.Median(Range("BY" & FirstVariable &":BY" & SecondVariable))
```

I tried this :

```
Range("BY" & ActiveCell.Row - CptM & ":BY" & ActiveCell.Row)
```

Where CptM is a Number

But I got the error : `"Execution code 91: Object Variable Or Bloc Variable With not defined.`

**What i want to do :**

[image]

I am using a For Loop to Browse J Column and to check Value Of J Cells

```
   For Cpt = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

MyString= Cells(Cpt - 1, 10).Value

    If Cells(Cpt, 10).Value = MyString Then

    CptM = CptM + 1

    End If

    If Cells(Cpt, 10).Value <> Metier Then
    MyVar= Application.Median(Range("BY" & ActiveCell.Row - CptM & ":BY" & ActiveCell.Row))
    Cells(Cpt, 81).Value = MyVar
    CptM = 0

    End If

Next Cpt
```

There i except to get the Median of the range R1 , R2 ect ...

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: What do you want to do with this Range ? I mean Copy it ? Select It ?

Comment: Please show more of your code.  Is your module `Option Explicit`?  Did you try to `Set rng = Range()`?  Are you using `With` and does it have an `End With`?

Comment: @Mikku I would like to do `Application.Median(MyRange)`

Comment: @Cyril I am using a **For** and There is a **Next** at the end but i am not using **With** statement

Comment: Do you actually have an Active Cell?  I'm not 100% certain you do.  Try replacing `ActiveCell.Row` with `Cpt`, like so: `MyVar= Application.Median(Range("BY" & Cpt - CptM & ":BY" & Cpt))`

Comment: @tigeravatar That was the problem, but i don't understand why when i do print Active Cell into a Message Box it display number ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to `ActiveCell.Row` because i didn't have Active Cells.

To handle this i just used `Cpt` in stead of `ActiveCell.Row`

The full line code is :

```
Application.Median(Range("BY" & Cpt - CptM & ":BY" & Cpt))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Application.Median(Range("BY" & ActiveCell.Row - CptM & ":BY" & ActiveCell.Row))
```

You can put this as a value in any variable.

Comment: I already tried this but i got the error code : _13 Type not compatible_

Comment: What is the range you are trying this on ? Can you put a screenshot of the numbers as a sample ?